# who do you prefer ObjectSet or CreateQuery in EF 4?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

i have been coding below. But i find another method secand part . which one is more preferable than other. what is the differece? whic one has more performance than other?

```
public T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return _context.CreateQuery<T>("[" + typeof(T).Name + "]").Where(predicate).Single();
}
```

ANOTHER USAGE

```
public T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return _objectSet.Single<T>(predicate);
}
```

which one is more prefer than other?

Comment: No need for HTML formatting in your post - see [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You're worried about *performance?* The first bit of code won't even *work* reliably!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are *completely* different things, with *completely* different purposes.

`ObjectSet<T>` is a strongly-typed property which allows you to run **LINQ** queries against the **conceptual** model.  (`ctx.Apples.Where(x => x.Color == "Red")`).

`CreateQuery<T>` is a method which allows you to run **native SQL** against the **physical** model. Also known as **EntitySQL**. (`SELECT * FROM dbo.Apples WHERE Color = "Red"`)

`ObjectSet<T>` is more type-safe, because entities on the model are exposed as properties on the ObjectSet, which is typed via generics. `CreateQuery<T>` on the other hand is also typed to the entity, but the actual query is EntitySQL, a string parameter - meaning possible runtime errors can occur because of typos. The only runtime errors you will get with `ObjectSet<T>` is CLR specific errors (null references, etc) or SQL specific errors (foreign key constraint, PK violation, etc).

As @adrift also mentions, `IObjectSet<T>` is mockable, however of course you could create a proxy/wrapper class for `CreateQuery<T>` and mock that.

I have used Entity Framework 4.0 for the past few months and have not found a single usage for `CreateQuery<T>`. I either use `ObjectSet<T>` or Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using `IObjectSet` since you can create a fake that implements `IObjectSet<TEntity>` for unit testing.  For a discussion of this, see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/834e27aa-b2e7-4900-ae1c-e8e1b02de4ba) and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/18/sneak-preview-entity-framework-4-0-testability-improvements.aspx).